# Deriving the velocity for circular orbital motion

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, celestial-mechanics

I'm trying to derive the (circular) orbital velocity for a given height from the center of mass of a body, like Earth.

First I used the equation of the circle $x^2 + y^2 = r^2$ to get $y = \pm \sqrt{r^2 - x^2}$. I then found the derivative to decide the slope of the velocity vector, which was $\pm \frac{x}{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}$.

The acceleration vector, though, will always be at 90 degrees the velocity vector, inwards towards the center of mass. The definition of perpendicular lines gives that the slopes must be the negative inverse of each other, so the acceleration vector must have a slope of $\pm \frac{\sqrt{r^2-x^2}}{x}$.

We also know that $v' = a$ must be true (the derivative of the velocity vector is the acceleration vector) and that $|a| = \frac{GM}{r^2}$, from Newton's Law of Gravity ($\frac{F}{m} = a = G \frac{Mm}{r^2 \cdot m}$).

How can I get $|v|$, knowing the slopes of the vectors and the magnitude of $a$? Is this a good approach? If not, how should I try to understand this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are trying to do this in Cartesian coordinates (x,y). This makes the math much harder than it needs to be.

It is more natural, when dealing with circular motion, to use polar coordinates - we express a position relative to the origin by its distance ($r$) and the angle relative to some reference axis ($\theta$). The relationship between $(x,y)$ and $(r,\theta)$ is given by

$$x = r \cos\theta\\
y = r \sin\theta$$

Now the solution becomes trivial. The velocity of an object in circular motion ($r$ is constant) is given by

$$|v| = r\omega = r \dot\theta$$

We know that the force needed to keep an object with mass $m$ in an orbit of radius $r$ at an angular velocity $\omega$ is

$$F = m \omega^2 r = \frac{m v^2}{r}$$

Setting this force equal to the force of gravity:

$$F_g = \frac{GMm}{r^2}$$

we find

$$ \frac{m v^2}{r} = \frac{GMm}{r^2}\\
v = \sqrt{\frac{GM}{r}}$$

Trying to get to the same answer while working with Cartesian coordinates is masochistic.

Answer (score 2):

Like on any circular motion you can use the relationship $a=v^2/r$, thus $|v|=\sqrt {ar}=\sqrt {GM/r}$